# Github: Building a docker image in a repository with multiple Dockerfile

Tags: docker, github-actions, github-package-registry

I have a repository that has multiple directories each containing a python script, a requirements.txt, and a Dockerfile. I want to use Github actions to build an image on merge to the main branch and push this image to Github packages. Each Dockerfile defines a running environment for the accompanying python script. But want to build only that directory's Dockerfile on which changes are made and tag each image with the directory name and a version number that is different from other directories version changes. How can I accomplish this? An example workflow.yml file would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

In order to trigger a separate build for every Dockerfile, you will need a separate workflow - e.g for every Dockerfile - one workflow. The workflows should be triggered on push to main and specify [paths](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpaths) for the Dockerfile.

For building the images themselves you can use GitHub Action [Build and push Docker images](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/build-and-push-docker-images)